# How to free an assigned static value in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, free

Valgrind reports that my code (showed below) is causing a memory leak.

```
view *vi = new view(IPs);
initialView = *vi;
//delete vi;
```

So, I added delete. But deleting vi makes `initialView` empty!! And causes several problems to valgrind. What shall I do?

By the way, This is the equal operator of class view!

```
view & operator = (const view& v){
        vp = std::vector <process>(v.vp);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Delete `initialView` once you've finished with it (and not before). Or use a smart pointer to do that for you. Or avoid using `new`. Or don't worry about the leak.

Comment: `deleting vi makes initialView empty`. I dont see why it should be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer is assigned a memory location from the heap or free store when you use the `new` command. The thing is, after using this memory location through the pointer, the programmer has to explicitly de-allocate that memory block using the `delete` command. Otherwise, the program will run out of dynamic memory and crash. Basically, that's what a memory leak leads to.

When the `delete pointer` is used, it simply resets the value of `pointer` to null and makes the memory block free for re usage. All you have to do is delete the pointer you use AFTER its designated use.
for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
    int* ptr=new int;
    *ptr=i;
    cout<<*ptr;  // ptr has been used, don't need it anymore
    delete ptr; //if you don't use this, memory leak will occur
    }
```

Comment: Please note, you cannot expect `delete` to reset the value of the pointer to null. See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this raw pointer with `shared_ptr` if possible. It's based on reference counting and hence can take care of freeing the memory when no one is pointing to it.

Comment: you are right, but I can't use smart pointers. This is just a sample of my code.

Comment: You might have a look at @Mike's comment then.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it's hard to tell. Which static variables are you referring to in the title?

For valgrind to be happy, you of course have to delete `vi`. In your code, I can't see any dependencies between `initialView` and `vi` after the assignment - the vector constructor creates a copy of `v`'s process list, and if those processes are not deleted with `vi`, this should be fine. If there are other dependencies causing you problems, try to eliminate them.